Store methods in class in order they are written
This might be a two part question. First is the context if better alternatives can be suggested. Second part is the (probably) XY problem for my solution.
xy - Have a method in the class which returns a list of all functions in the class in order they were written/typed.
My projects typically involve long sequences of queries/data transformations. I want to be able to wrap each step as a function so that the docstrings can be discoverable by those tools. But don't want to have to retype every function call at the end of each notebook.
Undesirable way:
def print_something_else():
  """
  Some docstring here
  """
  print("something else")
def print_some_other_thing():
  """
  Some other docstring here
  """
  print("something other thing")
def print_something():
  print("something")

print_something_else()
print_some_other_thing()
print_something()

I would like to just define the functions and have some wrapper so that they are run in order.
Attempt:
class RegisteredCommandSequence:
  def __init__(self):
    def __include(method):
      only_include_if = [
        type(getattr(self, method)).__name__ == 'method',
        not(method.startswith('__')),
        method not in ('run_all', 'run_from_to')]
      return all(only_include_if)
    
    self._public_nonbuiltin_callable_methods = [
      method for method in dir(self) if __include(method)]

  def run_all(self):
    for func in self._public_nonbuiltin_callable_methods:
      getattr(self, func)()

class QueryBundle(RegisteredCommandSequence):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
  def print_something_else(self):
    """
    Some docstring here
    """
    print("something else")
  def print_some_other_thing(self):
    """
    Some other docstring here
    """
    print("something other thing")
  def print_something(self):
    print("something")

test = QueryBundle()
test.run_all()

something other thing
something
something else

The problem is the dir() doesn't preserve the order in which the functions were written, which is vital.
If in the class itself I have a list of all the in-scope methods, it'd be very convenient to be able to run subsequences like test.run_from_to('print_something_else', 'print_some_other_thing').
Things I've considered

Decorators which dictate the order of execution of each.
Using the classes __dict__, which seems to preserve the order, but is empty when defined how I'm trying to use it.

example:
class ShowEmptyDict:
  def __init__(self):
    self.print_methods_in_class()
  
  def print_methods_in_class(self):
    return(self.__dict__)

demo = ShowEmptyDict()
if demo.print_methods_in_class():
  print('Not empty')
else:
  print('empty')


What was the point of the if demo.print_methods_in_class(): check?  The method doesn't return anything, so this code is always going to print "empty".

@jasonharper merp. My mistake. Edited to actually demo what I was trying to show.

Unrelated: I noticed you use 2 spaces of indentation. You should get in the habit of writing PEP-8 compliant code with 4 spaces of indentation.

@Friedrich Agreed on that one. Internal style convention I'm not a big fan of.

I would advise against source code order dictating execution order, but if you really need to, you can use inspect.getsourcelines() to get the line number where an object starts at.
import inspect


class Funcs:
    def func_8(self):
        pass

    def func_5(self):
        pass

    def func_4(self):
        pass


instance = Funcs()

funcs = [getattr(instance, func) for func in dir(instance) if inspect.ismethod(getattr(instance, func))]
funcs.sort(key=lambda func: inspect.getsourcelines(func)[1])
print(funcs)

prints out
[
 <bound method Funcs.func_8 of <__main__.Funcs object at 0x1175b0740>>,
 <bound method Funcs.func_5 of <__main__.Funcs object at 0x1175b0740>>, 
 <bound method Funcs.func_4 of <__main__.Funcs object at 0x1175b0740>>,
]

This generalizes to any namespace where you have functions, of course, not just a class instance.

Accepting this answer because it solves the problem as posed. Noted and agreed on the design concerns.

nice way to bypass dunder methods (and/or other implicitly defined methods)

You can use class attributes and decorators to store order
Try this code, this code works perfectly well to do.
class RegisteredCommandSequence:
    _method_order = []

    @classmethod
    def _register_method(cls, func):
        cls._method_order.append(func.__name__)
        return func

    def run_all(self):
        for func_name in self._method_order:
            getattr(self, func_name)()

class QueryBundle(RegisteredCommandSequence):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @_register_method
    def print_something_else(self):
        """
        Some docstring here
        """
        print("something else")

    @_register_method
    def print_some_other_thing(self):
        """
        Some other docstring here
        """
        print("something other thing")

    @_register_method
    def print_something(self):
        print("something")

test = QueryBundle()
test.run_all()


Nice idea, but this gives me a NameError. Also, is there a reason to store the name of the method and not the method itself?

Good approach. @_register_method should be @RegisteredCommandSequence._register_method?

Similar to what Johan suggested, but a bit simpler, without classes (but should work just the same for methods of some class): You can use a simple Decorator function to mark function to be called later. This will add the functions to a list in the order they are defined, and you can later iterate that list and call the methods.
run_later_functions = []

def run_later(f):
    run_later_functions.append(f)

@run_later
def first():
    print("first")

@run_later
def second():
    print("second")

def helper():
    print("used somewhere else, don't run")

@run_later
def last():
    print("last")

for function in run_later_functions:
    function()


Very nice. Thank you. I think all things considered this approach is best. Accepted the other answer because for better or worse it solves the problem as worded in the title.

Similar to the answer of AKX, but with no extra imports.
Used code object to retrieve the line number corresponding the declaration in the source code. code object represents the compiled function body.
cls = Funcs

my_methods = []
for m_name in dir(cls):
    method = getattr(cls, m_name)
    if hasattr(method, '__code__'):
        my_methods.append((method.__code__.co_firstlineno, m_name))

# sort by line number in the source code
my_methods.sort()
# decouple line numbers from method identifiers
_, my_methods = zip(*my_methods)

# display the result
print(my_methods)


The following (more compact) implementation wants to follow the point "2 of the OP. Using the classes dict, [...]", using the natural ordering of the dict. To track classmethods and staticmethods a further check is needed. Here the main part:
cls = Funcs

my_methods = []
for method in cls.__dict__.values():
    # check if classmethod/staticmethod
    if isinstance(method, (classmethod, staticmethod)):
        method = method.__wrapped__

    if hasattr(method, '__code__'):
        my_methods.append(method.__name__)

# display the result
print(my_methods)


The above code can be put inside of a class method and/or can be used as class decorator.

Two part answer to a two part question. First, the XY bit -- just write a secondary attribute that stores the functions in the order you would like to call them. It's simple, concise, and get across your point/idea.
Recommended Solution
class Foo:
    def first(self): return 'first'
    def second(self): return 'second'
    def third(self): return 'third'
    def _but_not_me(self): raise Exception
    def or_me(self): raise Exception

    def apply(self):
        # N.B. you need to explicitly pass self, as the functions are not bound methods
        return [func(self) for func in self._method_order]:

    # may be initialised before apply(), must be after the functions it references
    _method_order = [first, second, third]

assert Foo().apply() == ['first', 'second', 'third']

Direct Solution
Second, how to get access to methods in the order they were defined, perhaps even across classes? Classes, like objects (class instances) have dicts that store their attributes. And since python 3.7, these dicts must retain the order in which keys were inserted. We can use this to leverage this to get the order that functions were declared in the class body. In combination with __init_subclass__, we can automatically generate this list and even configure how the list is generated.
class MethodCollector:
    """Base class that collects the functions of its children"""
    _method_order = []

    def __init_subclass__(
        cls,
        filter=None, # type: Callable[[str, Callable], bool] | None
        reorder_on_update=False,
        include_parents=False,
        include_private=False
    ):
        """filter is an optional callable that takes the name a function is stored as 
        and the function itself. Returns true if the function should be included."""
        def composite_filter(name, func):
            return (
                (include_private or not name.startswith('_'))
                and (filter is None or filter(name, func))
            )

        if include_parents:
            cls_search = reversed(cls.mro())
        else:
            cls_search = iter([cls])
        
        methods = {}
        for candidate_cls in cls_search:
            cls_dict = candidate_cls.__dict__
            for name, func in cls_dict.items():
                if callable(func) and composite_filter(name, func):
                    if reorder_on_update and name in methods:
                        del methods[name]
                    methods[name] = func
        
        cls._method_order = list(methods.values())

Example usage:
# basic usage
class ChildA(MethodCollector):
    def first(self): pass
    def _not_collected(self): pass
    def a_second(self): pass # lexicographically first, but declared second
    not_collected = 123 # not a function, so not collected

def all_lower(name, func):
    return name.lower() == name

# example on how to configure method collection
class ChildB(ChildA, include_parents=True, filter=all_lower):
    def third(self): pass
    def NOT_ME(self): pass
    def first(self): pass # (re)declared last, but order does not change as it is an
                          # overridden method

# example showing an overridden method appearing later in the method order 
class ChildC(ChildA, include_parents=True, reorder_on_update=True):
    def first(self): pass # now last

assert ChildA._method_order == [ChildA.first, ChildA.a_second]
assert ChildB._method_order == [ChildB.first, ChildB.a_second, ChildB.third]
assert ChildC._method_order == [ChildC.a_second, ChildC.first]

